# How can you determine how a console application was launched?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, console, console-application

How can I tell whether the user launched my console application by double-clicking the EXE (or a shortcut), or whether they already had a command line window open and executed my console app within that session?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Win32 console application detect if it has been run from the explorer or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510805/can-a-win32-console-application-detect-if-it-has-been-run-from-the-explorer-or-no)

Answer (score 10):

Stick this static field in your "`Program`" class to ensure it runs before any output:

```
static bool StartedFromGui = 
         !Console.IsOutputRedirected
      && !Console.IsInputRedirected
      && !Console.IsErrorRedirected
      && Environment.UserInteractive
      && Environment.CurrentDirectory == System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
      && Console.CursorTop == 0 && Console.CursorLeft == 0
      && Console.Title == Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]
      && Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0] == System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

This is a little bit overkill/paranoid, but picks up being started from Explorer while not responding to things like `cls && app.exe` (by checking for the full path) or even `cls && "f:\ull\path\to\app.exe"` (by looking at the title).

I got the idea from the [win32 version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508093/determine-if-program-is-run-from-cmd-or-from-explorer).

Comment: I added a second field `static bool startedFromVisualStudio =
    !Console.IsOutputRedirected
    && !Console.IsInputRedirected
    && !Console.IsErrorRedirected
    && Environment.UserInteractive
    && Environment.CurrentDirectory == System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
    && Console.CursorTop == 0 && Console.CursorLeft == 0
    && Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0].Contains("vshost");` to also wait for a keypress when launched from VS

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to figure it out by P/Invoking to the Win32 [*GetStartupInfo()*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683230(v=VS.85).aspx) function.

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern void GetStartupInfo([In, Out] STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what the parent process is:

```
    Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()?.Parent()?.ProcessName);
```

Where Parent() is an extension method, e.g.:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static string FindIndexedProcessName(int pid)
    {
        var processName = Process.GetProcessById(pid).ProcessName;
        var processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        string processIndexdName = null;

        for (var index = 0; index < processesByName.Length; index++)
        {
            processIndexdName = index == 0 ? processName : processName + "#" + index;
            var processId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", processIndexdName);
            if ((int)processId.NextValue() == pid)
            {
                return processIndexdName;
            }
        }

        return processIndexdName;
    }

    private static Process FindPidFromIndexedProcessName(string indexedProcessName)
    {
        var parentId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process ID", indexedProcessName);
        return Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId.NextValue());
    }

    public static Process Parent(this Process process)
    {
        return FindPidFromIndexedProcessName(FindIndexedProcessName(process.Id));
    }
}
```