# Detecting if a Winform was launched from the console?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, cmd

How I can detect if my application is launched from the console, or from "explorer"?

What I want to do is, if application is launched from CMD then show a little info on CMD, only if application is launched from CMD and without any arguments so I can't detect the arguments.

The project is a Windowsform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527555/how-can-you-determine-how-a-console-application-was-launched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB Code:

```
#Region " App Is Launched From CMD? "

    ' [ App Is Launched From CMD? Function ]
    '
    ' // By Elektro H@cker
    '
    ' Examples:
    ' MsgBox(App_Is_Launched_From_CMD)
    ' If App_Is_Launched_From_CMD() Then Console.WriteLine("Help for this application: ...")

    Declare Function AttachConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwProcessId As Int32) As Boolean
    Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Boolean

    Private Function App_Is_Launched_From_CMD()
        If AttachConsole(-1) Then
            FreeConsole()
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

#End Region
```