# Determine if Program is Run from CMD or from Explorer

Tags: c#, command-line, directory

In C#, is there a way to determine if program has been run from the command line (CMD.exe) or from explorer (any folder view, etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: There are several stackoverflow questions on how to get the parent process, which may provide what you are looking for. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way

Comment: See Hans Passant's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2533287/187697).

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63135555/10413298)